# Is there a way to add a gitignore template to new projects in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

When creating a new repository in Azure Devops you are prompted to choose a .gitignore template file.
Is there a way to add your own template file to this dropdown list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do this at the moment.

This list is just the same as GitHub’s collection of .gitignore file templates. We use this list to populate the .gitignore template choosers available in the Azure DevOps Web interface when creating new repositories and files.

For detail info about each template you could refer  [A collection of .gitignore templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore)

As a workaround, you may have to select a none template first.  Then you can add it manually  by touch .gitignore, and copy the content in your .gitignore file. Or directly check in your local customized .gitignore file.

Comment: This answer is for Azure DevOps Service, Server, both?